# How a code can be assigned to an Application custom error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rails-i18n, i18n-gem

How a code can be given to an Application custom error messages in Ruby on Rails. when a user sees an error, he should be able to know both its error code and message.

**For example**, I want to achieve the following result, in case of respective error.

```
CODE  Message    
4081  You are not allowed to view the private document 
5082  Company with this name already present
5034  Page removed
```

This is a multilingual application. Translations for error messages are present in /config/locales/en.yml. I'm using i18n gem for translation. This is how translation for error messages are present without code.

```
errors:
  messages:
    private_document: "You are not allowed to view the private document" 
    company_name: "Company with this name already present" 
    page_remove: "Page removed"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this are you looking for?....

```
errors:
  messages:
    4081 "You are not allowed to view the private document" 
    5082 "Company with this name already present" 
    5034 "Bidding end date should be greater than current date and time"
```

Use code instead of name.